# Can accepted answers be changed now?

Tags: support

My reputation just went down by 15 points for some reason.  I think my answer was accepted at one point for [PSU power cable length, and will my graphics card fit in my case?](https://superuser.com/q/373072/1734), but now the other answer is accepted.

Did that actually just happen?  If so, when did that become possible?  Or has it always been possible and I just didn't realize it?

Losing a bit of reputation doesn't bother me, I'm just curious what the heck happened and if I'm imagining / seeing things.

**Update**

OK, so it looks like I didn't realize the OP can change accepted answers at any time.  No big deal.  I guess the only way to know this has happened is to notice the missing reputation and notice that one of your answers is no longer the accepted one.

Comment: The notifications could be improved there, that's true. AFAIK, it just removes the +15 from the rep history, instead of adding a -15 when a post is unaccepted.

Comment: @DanielBeck while this used to be true, they [changed the page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107007/147926) in September so as long as the accept and unaccept don't occur on the same day you should see both separately.

Comment: @DMA57361 This is cool, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a new change, for as long as I can remember question owners have been able to do this (because, well, you never know when a better answer will come along).

If one of your answers is accepted→unaccepted (or unaccepted→accepted) in a single day then there's no real way to check that without noticing by chance (as you have here), however if these events happen on *different days* both events will appear in the rep tab on your profile on the day they happened.

If you want to check if this has happened on a *specific question* you can use the (vaguely hidden / unsupported) time line feature, which can only be accessed by a bit some URL adjustment:

For example, https://superuser.com/posts/373072/timeline (note the Q's number in there from the normal URL) will take you to the time line of the question you've linked and from there you can clearly see that:

- Your answer was accepted at 7:46 on the 30th.
- The accept was moved to Melikoth's answer at 11:25 on the same day.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Yes,** the OP can change the accepted answer at any time. The only way to see it has changed, is that you just lost 15 rep, or notice one of your answers is no longer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you asked the question, the `title` (tooltip) attribute for the `vote-accepted` links read "Click to set this answer as your accepted answer; click again to toggle." So, yes, users have the choice to reject an accepted answer.